# How can I update data with FutureBuilder widget in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cross-platform

I am simply dealing with FutureBuilder widget in Flutter, and I am taking a number data from my firebase, then show that data inside of the Button's text. Before the showing, I am loading data in the screen and it is showing loading text with disabled button, when data uploaded It shows number data in the enable button  from my firebase.

I want to upload data then I press to that enable button, and it should show saving text in the button then loading text again. Finally, It should updated number. How can I handle this problem?

**I am taking that in here:**

```
Future getData() async {
  var fb = Firestore.instance;

  DocumentSnapshot dr =  (await fb.collection("records").document("the record").get());

  return dr.data.toString();
}
```

**And here is my FutureBuilder widget:**

```
 child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (_ ,snapshot){

                if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return RaisedButton(
                    child: Text("loading" ),
                    onPressed: null,
                  );
                }


                if(snapshot.connectionState==ConnectionState.done) {
                  return RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(snapshot.data),
                    onPressed: updateData,
                  );
                }
```

**And I simply try to implement updateData function for update data from the firebase, but It also should include saving state in the FutureBuilder.**

```
void updateData() async {

  int value=0;

  var fb = Firestore.instance;

  await fb.collection("records").document("the record").updateData(
      {
        "value" : value+1,
      }
  );

}
```

How can I uptade that daha when I press the button, and how can I put the state to saving and loading state inside of the FutureBuilder?